# I have an idea through utilizing soda lime or other basic substances to help solve climate change

Tags: carbon-family

I have an idea through utilizing soda lime or other basic substances to help solve climate change. I want to see if there are some possible errors or other negative implication that I am disregarding.

I came across soda lime during one of my biology textbooks and noticed that it has the ability to absorb $\ce{CO2}$. The first thing that popped into my head was utilising soda lime ($\ce{CaHNaO2}$) to help solve global warming.

My idea is having large or wide buildings that are made with soda lime on the edge that will "suck up" the carbon dioxide. This carbon dioxide can then be used for various different ways in which the community and the society can benefit from.

1. convert it to electricity or fuel (it has been said that there is a way of doing this as in Cornell University Research - [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pu13bzfos2U)). Essentially, the electricity made would be redistributed to the city  to use.
2. export the gas to bread industries (the yeast produces carbon dioxide that may be used for brewing and for bakery)
3. if possible, change the carbon dioxide to oxygen and release oxygen.

I know I might not be aware of some factors and it may seem idealistic, but I want to hear from the community. Is what I am proposing realistic enough? Or are there some practical problems with this approach?

Comment: Limestone already contains CO2. It won't take up more. Especially removing it from limestone consumes a lot of energy, and further converting it to fuel would need even more energy. Yeast *produces* CO2, and the amount is totally negligible in comparison to our greenhouse problem. Lastly, converting CO2 to carbon and O2 also takes up a huge amount of energy.

Comment: Soda-lime deteriorates unless kept in an airtight container leading to waste of resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My worry is that the energy requirements for making soda lime, caustic soda or some other carbon dioxide adsorber will be so high that overall it will result in the emission of more green house gases.

Years ago I was touring a waste disposal site where they react waste sulfuric acid with limestone. The boss of the site told me that some years ago someone had asked if he could scrub out the carbon dioxide from the reaction tank with sodium hydroxide or a similar reagent. He gave the same answer as I am giving to us when he recalled the tale.